# ffmpeg video and audio out of sync, slower (44100 to 48000)

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube-dl, twitch, audacity

I downloaded few live videos from Twitch using a youtube-dl command, but in the original video the audio have sampling rate in 48000 and youtube-dl saved the video in 44100, turning the video slower and the audio pitched. When i opened the audio on audacity and change the sampling rate 44100 to 48000, the timing and pitch of the audio was fixed, but my question is: **Someone here knows how to fix it these files using ffmpeg, fixing the video running time and the audio pitch?**

Well, I would like to have a command that I could fix just by rendering without converting the file, but if it's the only solution is converting, I accept.

Thank you for you time, and I appreciate your attention!